# clangd mangling system include paths

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, nvcc, clangd

Running `clangd --check=my_file.cu` I get something along these lines (simplified):

```
I[13:05:09.356] Testing on source file /path/to/my_file.cu
I[13:05:09.362] Loading compilation database...
I[13:05:09.363] Loaded compilation database from /path/to/build/compile_commands.json
I[13:05:09.364] Compile command from CDB is: /path/to/bin/nvcc [...] -isystem=/path/to/lib/include [...] -- /path/to/my_file.cu
[...]
I[13:05:09.364] Parsing command...
I[13:05:09.371] internal (cc1) args are: -cc1 [...] -isystem =/path/to/lib/include [...] -x cuda /path/to/my_file.cu
```

Crucially, there is a difference between the command in the compilation database and the parsed internal command. Namely, `-isystem=/path/to/lib/include` becomes `-isystem =/path/to/lib/include` (with a space). It appears clangd is not properly parsing the `=` syntax for the system includes.

Clangd is then unable to find the includes for libs installed system-wide unless I manually add `-I /path/to/lib/include` with the clangd config file.

The form `-isystem=/path/to/lib/include` is being generated by CMake in the compile commands, and works fine when compiling with NVCC/GCC. However, clangd appears to be misreading this as the path `=/path/to/lib/include` rather than `/path/to/lib/include`.

This is with C++/CUDA libraries, but I don't *think* that is the root cause.

Is there some way to get clangd to properly parse the `-isystem` flags generated by CMake for NVCC? Is this a bug, or is it consistent with clang's expected behaviour?

### Minimum reproducible example

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(demo LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

# Download GoogleTest
include(FetchContent)
message(STATUS "> Downloading dependency: GoogleTest")
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/refs/tags/v1.14.0.zip
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)
message(STATUS "> Downloading dependency: GoogleTest - done")

# Build demo executable
add_executable(demo demo.cu)
target_link_libraries(demo GTest::gtest_main)
```

```
// demo.cu
#include <iostream>

int main() { std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl; }
```

When configuring with `cmake -B build .`, we get the following compile DB:

```
[
{
  "directory": "/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build",
  "command": "/path/to/bin/nvcc -forward-unknown-to-host-compiler  -isystem=/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include -isystem=/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest  --generate-code=arch=compute_52,code=[compute_52,sm_52] -std=c++17 -x cu -c /home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/demo.cu -o CMakeFiles/demo.dir/demo.cu.o",
  "file": "/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/demo.cu"
},
{
  "directory": "/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-build/googlemock",
  "command": "/local/scratch/sbone/mambaforge/envs/cudaj_devel/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++  -I/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googlemock/include -I/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googlemock -isystem /home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include -isystem /home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /local/scratch/sbone/mambaforge/envs/cudaj_devel/include -Wall -Wshadow -Wundef -Wno-error=dangling-else -DGTEST_HAS_PTHREAD=1 -fexceptions -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -o CMakeFiles/gmock.dir/src/gmock-all.cc.o -c /home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googlemock/src/gmock-all.cc",
  "file": "/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googlemock/src/gmock-all.cc"
},
{
  "directory": "/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-build/googlemock",
  "command": "/local/scratch/sbone/mambaforge/envs/cudaj_devel/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++  -isystem /home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googlemock/include -isystem /home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googlemock -isystem /home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include -isystem /home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /local/scratch/sbone/mambaforge/envs/cudaj_devel/include -Wall -Wshadow -Wundef -Wno-error=dangling-else -DGTEST_HAS_PTHREAD=1 -fexceptions -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -o CMakeFiles/gmock_main.dir/src/gmock_main.cc.o -c /home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googlemock/src/gmock_main.cc",
  "file": "/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googlemock/src/gmock_main.cc"
},
{
  "directory": "/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-build/googletest",
  "command": "/local/scratch/sbone/mambaforge/envs/cudaj_devel/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++  -I/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include -I/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /local/scratch/sbone/mambaforge/envs/cudaj_devel/include -Wall -Wshadow -Wundef -Wno-error=dangling-else -DGTEST_HAS_PTHREAD=1 -fexceptions -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -o CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o -c /home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc",
  "file": "/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc"
},
{
  "directory": "/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-build/googletest",
  "command": "/local/scratch/sbone/mambaforge/envs/cudaj_devel/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++  -isystem /home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include -isystem /home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /local/scratch/sbone/mambaforge/envs/cudaj_devel/include -Wall -Wshadow -Wundef -Wno-error=dangling-else -DGTEST_HAS_PTHREAD=1 -fexceptions -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -o CMakeFiles/gtest_main.dir/src/gtest_main.cc.o -c /home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc",
  "file": "/home/sbone/repos/cmake_mvp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc"
}
]
```

As you can see, the CUDA code has the system includes specified with `-isystem=...`.

Note: this is with CMake 3.24.3 and NVCC `cuda_12.2.r12.2/compiler.33191640_0`.

Comment: Clangd does it correctly. The properly set option is `-isystem /path/to/lib/include` w/o = and with the optional space. `-isystem=/path/to/lib/include` sets the wrong path `=/path/to/lib/include`. I doubt it is generated by CMake. Show a [mcve].

Comment: @273K Thank you for the reply. The flags `-isystem=...` are indeed being generated by CMake. I will add an MRE example.

Comment: It's generated for GCC, GCC replaces `=` with -sysroot path. This is not compatible with clangd. If your use clangd, then use clang.

Comment: I don't think clangd is a suitable checker for demo.cu.

Comment: Unfortunately compiling the project with Clang is not an option; it is a CUDA project which uses the NVCC/GCC toolchain. We're only using clangd as an LSP for our IDEs. As I mentioned, it works fine if we manually add the system includes in question via `.clangd`. I guess there is no automated way to get clangd to recognise the `-isystem=*` style of flags?

Comment: You can use different cmake binary dirs for clangd with clang and GCC builds.

Answer (score 0):

Clang indeed does not accept the `-isystem=` format of the flag. (You can see this from the way the option is defined in the [clang source](https://searchfox.org/llvm/rev/d218092543b3f9ba2204d7c8fe5ac70befa3d772/clang/include/clang/Driver/Options.td#4271). Flags which accept `=`, like `--sysroot`, have a [_EQ](https://searchfox.org/llvm/rev/d218092543b3f9ba2204d7c8fe5ac70befa3d772/clang/include/clang/Driver/Options.td#5652) form, and `-isystem` does not.)

So, if `nvcc` accepts `-isystem=`, then this looks like a subtle inconsistency between the command-line argument syntax of `clang` and `nvcc`. (Possibly unintentional; assuming `nvcc` is the one trying to be compatible with `clang` here, this could be worth filing an `nvcc` issue about so its developers are aware.)

Clangd uses the clang driver to process the commands in `compile_commands.json`, so it accepts whatever clang accepts.

Assuming `nvcc` indeed accepts `-isystem=`, CMake generating an `nvcc` command using `-isystem=` is not a CMake bug *per se*... but if `nvcc` also accepts `-isystem` with no equals, maybe it would be better for CMake to use the more portable form of the flag? (Could be worth a CMake issue.)

For the time being, I think your options are:

1. Somehow get CMake to generate a command using the `-isystem` form. I'm not familiar enough with CMake to make a concrete suggestion, but perhaps you can get it to generate a `clang` command rather than an `nvcc` command? (You don't have to actually *run* the `clang` command during the build.)

   **or**
2. Adjust the compile command using the [clangd config file](https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html#compileflags). You can remove the incorrect form of the flag and add the correct one using `CompileFlags:`.